# Grepl in for do loop, by passing string

Tags: r

```
mdma4 <- unique(mdma4)    
output <- c()
for (i in 1:length(mdma4)){
  m <- (mdma4[i])
  result <- mdma$MRP.Area[grepl('m', mdma$Material)]
  if (length(result) == 0 ){
    print('in if')
    output <- c(output, result)
  }
}
```

`mdma4` contains vector: `c("A", "B", ...)`. `mdma` is data frame with 2 columns.

I am trying to pass a string from `mdma4` into `mdma$Material` and find the corresponding entries from `mdma$MRP`. Area
But the `grepl` code is not fetching data from corresponding column.

It is partial string matching outside the loop, the following code works, but if it is in for do loop, not working.

```
test <- mdma$MRP.Area[grepl("GK180", mdma$Material)]
```

Comment: Use the comments or update the question if providing additional information or requesting clarification.  It's not helpful to copy an answer and then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you're looking for full string or partial string matching.  One of the following should work:

```
mdma$MRP.Area[grepl(m, mdma$Material)] #remove quotes around m

mdma$MRP.Area[grepl(mdma4[i], mdma$Material)] #not creating variable m

mdma$MRP.Area[mdma$Material == mdma4[i]] #full string match
```

FYI, a closing `}` is missing

Answer (score 0):

all of the following not working, when it is inside loop
But working outside the for loop

```
mdma$MRP.Area[grepl(m, mdma$Material)] #remove quotes around m

mdma$MRP.Area[grepl(mdma4[i], mdma$Material)] #not creating variable m

mdma$MRP.Area[mdma$Material == mdma4[i]]
```